# HtmlUnit HtmlSubmitInput.click() results in "Incorrect URL" corrected to "cgi-bin" which then leads to an UnknownHostException

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

I am trying to write a little bot that is supposed to access this site http://lsa.colorado.edu/cgi-bin/LSA-pairwise.html, enter some text in the textarea and fetch the resulting page from submitting by pressing the submit button. This is for a linguistics project.
However, when I execute the click on the HtmlSubmitInput Button the returned URL seems to be malformed as IncorrectnessListenerImpl notifies me:

```
Apr 10, 2016 2:38:35 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNUNG: Incorrect URL "http:/cgi-bin/LSA-pairwise-x.html" has been corrected
```

The URL should be

> http://lsa.colorado.edu/cgi-bin/LSA-pairwise-x.html

This then leads to the following stacktrace (shortened due to length):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: cgi-bin: unknown error
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.download(WebClient.java:2078)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm.submit(HtmlForm.java:141)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput.doClickStateUpdate(HtmlSubmitInput.java:90)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:795)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:742)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:689)
    at LSABot.submitInput(LSABot.java:30)
    at Start.main(Start.java:8)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
 [...]
```

My guess is that HtmlUnit tries to fix the URL but this results in only "cgi-bin", which of course is malformed. 
I've searched over and over but have not found anything relevant for my issue.

My LSABot class:

```
public class LSABot {
    final WebClient webClient;
    private HtmlPage mainPg, rsltPg;
    private HtmlForm htmlForm;
    private HtmlTextArea txtA;
    private HtmlSubmitInput submitBt;

    public LSABot () throws Exception {
        this.webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        this.webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        this.mainPg = this.webClient.getPage("http://lsa.colorado.edu/cgi-bin/LSA-pairwise.html");
        this.htmlForm = this.mainPg.getForms().get(0);
        this.txtA = this.htmlForm.getTextAreaByName("txt1");
        this.submitBt = this.htmlForm.getInputByValue("Submit Texts");
    }

    public void submitInput(String input) {
        this.txtA.setText(input);
        try {
            this.rsltPg = this.submitBt.click();
            this.webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(30*1000);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from the html content of the form. The `action` attribute should be `http://lsa.colorado.edu/cgi-bin/LSA-pairwise-x.html` instead of `http:/cgi-bin/LSA-pairwise-x.html`.

Try this code, it should work:

```
LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");

java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF); 
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.OFF);

WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);

String url = "http://lsa.colorado.edu/cgi-bin/LSA-pairwise.html";
final HtmlPage page = client.getPage(url);

HtmlForm htmlForm = page.getForms().get(0);
HtmlTextArea txtA = htmlForm.getTextAreaByName("txt1");
txtA.setText("hello");
HtmlSubmitInput submitBt = htmlForm.getInputByValue("Submit Texts");

// change the form action attribute to the correct one  
htmlForm.setAttribute("action", "http://lsa.colorado.edu/cgi-bin/LSA-pairwise-x.html");

HtmlPage page2 = submitBt.click();
System.out.println(page2.asText());
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you! The HtmlForm.setAttribute() method was exactly what I needed!